In CUDA, what is the right way to perform a block-wise sum?
Suppose I want to find the block-sum of a local int X. The naive way to do it would be to just use atomicAdd with a __shared__ variable:
__device__ int blocksum(int x) {
  __shared__ int sum;
  
  sum = 0;
  __syncthreads();

  atomicAdd(&sum, X);
  __syncthreads();

  return sum;
}

As far as I understand, though, doing so should be avoided, as this is a single point of contention and will cause all threads to execute sequentially. As such, I started looking for a faster / easier way to do it, but couldn't find any answer. I've implemented 2 alternatives: a block-wise scansum, a mix of __reduce_add_sync and atomicAdd; yet, both performed worse than atomicAdd.
Is there some kind of "add broadcast" optimization happening under the hoods? Is a simple atomicAdd the right way to perform a block-wise sum?

The general methodology is a parallel reduction.  There are numerous questions here on the cuda SO tag about it, and it is covered in some detail with several options in unit 5 of this online training series. cub library also has options.  Nowadays atomics are pretty fast.  you may or may not find anything faster.

@RobertCrovella good info, thanks! Just for context, I've spent the whole way reading (including that link), implemented the parallel sums, managed to get a very fast one with warpsync - https://gist.github.com/VictorTaelin/f3179fc5e93a50570fa252cf01b62aa0, but, somehow, atomicAdd is the fastest, which motivated the question. I also looked many questions here, but, for some reason, there is none about block-wise sum of a single int specifically! I wonder if CUDA is doing some magic under the hoods for atomicAdd.

The compiler may implement warp-aggregated atomics.  This means that instead of doing an atomic for every thread, it is using a shuffle op to get the sum across a warp, then each warp does a single  atomic (i.e. from one thread in the warp).  You would have to study the SASS, to see if this is happening in any particular case, or not.

You are correct that doing a blockwide atomicAdd will cause significant slowdown due to add threads serializing when all threads add to the same address.
There is one exception, if you atomicAdd(address, boolean). In that case the GPU will execute the following psuedo code instead.
const auto count = __popc(__ballot_sync(__activemask(), boolean));
if ((threadIdx.x % 32) == 0) { atomicAdd(address, count); }

Another problem with your code is that __reduce_add_sync is extremely slow. I suspect that this is just a preview feature that is implemented in microcode in Ampere (it does compile to a single SASS upcode). It is always slower than any code you can write yourself.
The slowdown gets much worse if not all threads have the same mask.
For example the following code to merge duplicate items:
const auto i = threadIdx.x / 2 + 1;
const auto dupemask = __match_any_sync(-1u, i & 0xFFFFFFFE);
const auto merged_i = __reduce_or_sync(dupemask, i); //16x slower than atomicOr 

Let's do some comparisons:
__global__ void testAtomic(int i) {
    __shared__ int counter;
    counter = 0;
    __syncthreads();
    const auto StartTime = clock64(); //do not use clock32! it is slow.
    atomicAdd(&counter, i);
    __syncthreads(); //wait for atomicAdd to resolve, or timings will be off
    const auto EndTime = clock64();
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        printf("testAtomic<<<1, %i>>>(%i): total = %i, should be: %i, time = %i cycles\n", blockDim.x, i, counter, i * blockDim.x, int(EndTime - StartTime));
    }
}

testAtomic<<<1,1024>>>(10): total = 10240, should be: 10240, time = 748 cycles
__global__ void testReduceAddSync(int i) {
    __shared__ int counter;
    __shared__ int counters[32]; //1024 /warpsize = 32 warps max
    counter = 0;
    counters[threadIdx.x % 32] = 0;

    __syncthreads();
    const auto StartTime = clock64(); //do not use clock32! it is slow.
    counters[threadIdx.x / 32] = __reduce_add_sync(-1u, i);
    __syncthreads();
    if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
        counter = __reduce_add_sync(-1u, counters[threadIdx.x]);
    }
    __syncthreads(); //wait for atomicAdd to resolve, or timings will be off
    const auto EndTime = clock64();
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        printf("testReduceAddSync<<<1, %i>>>(%i): total = %i, should be: %i, time = %i cycles\n", blockDim.x, i, counter, i * blockDim.x, int(EndTime - StartTime));
    }
}

testReduceAddSync<<<1,1024>>>(10): total = 10240, should be: 10240, time = 594 cycles
__global__ void testShflDown(int i) {
    __shared__ int counter;
    counter = 0;
    auto sum = i;
    __syncthreads();
    const auto StartTime = clock64(); //do not use clock32! it is slow.
    sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 1);
    sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 2);
    sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 4);
    sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 8);
    sum += __shfl_down_sync(-1u, sum, 16);

    if ((threadIdx.x % 32) == 0) { atomicAdd(&counter, sum); }
    __syncthreads(); //wait for atomicAdd to resolve, or timings will be off
    const auto EndTime = clock64();
    if (threadIdx.x == 0) {
        printf("testShflDown<<<1, %i>>>(%i): total = %i, should be: %i, time = %i cycles\n", blockDim.x, i, counter, i * blockDim.x, int(EndTime - StartTime));
    }
}
  

testShflDown<<<1,1024>>>(10): total = 10240, should be: 10240, time = 494 cycles
Let's hope that Blackwell has proper support for the __reduce_xxx_sync functions, so they are actually good for something in the future.

Great answer. Are you open to work? We have a very well-paid position to help us optimize a specific CUDA software. The code is simple and clean (2k LOC), it is pretty fast but we'd like to experiment some variations, and I'm sure you'd be able to add a lot of value. Let me know in any case...

Sure, how do I contact you? At HigherOrderCo.com?
